# When to use TouchableNativeFeedback, TouchableHighlight or TouchableOpacity?

Tags: react-native

In React Native, there are at least three ways to make a button: `TouchableNativeFeedback`, `TouchableHighlight` and `TouchableOpacity`. There is also `TouchableWithoutFeedback`, which the documentation clearly states you should not use because "all the elements that respond to press should have a visual feedback when touched".

- [TouchableNativeFeedback](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.31/docs/touchablenativefeedback.html#touchablenativefeedback) is Android only and "replaces the View with another instance of RCTView"
- [TouchableHighlight](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchablehighlight.html#touchablehighlight) "adds a view to the view hierarchy"
- [TouchableOpacity](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchableopacity.html#touchableopacity) works "without changing the view hierarchy"

Are there any other significant differences between the three? Is one of them the goto component? In what case should you use `TouchableHighlight` over `TouchableOpacity`? Are there any performance implications?

I am writing an application right now, and find that all three have a significant delay between tap and the action (in this case a navigation change). Is there any way to make it snappier?

Comment: As far as snappiness is concerned... outputting anything to console.log slows down scene transitions considerably. I'm just getting started in react native and was somewhat un-impressed of the speed while developing my first components. I removed all console.log commands (including disabling redux logger) and built for release target and the speed blew me away. This is coming from developing Cordova apps.

Answer (score 156, accepted):

source: https://medium.com/differential/better-cross-platform-react-native-components-cb8aadeba472, by Nick Wientge

`TouchableHighlight`

• What it does: Darkens or lightens the background of the element when pressed.

• When to use it: On iOS for touchable elements or buttons that have a solid shape or background, and on ListView items.

`TouchableOpacity`

• What it does: Lightens the opacity of the entire element when pressed.

• When to use it: On iOS for touchable elements that are standalone text or icons with no background color.

`TouchableNativeFeedback`

• What it does: Adds a ripple effect to the background when pressed.

• When to use it: On Android for almost all touchable elements.

Comment: Thank you! I had read this article since, but couldn't find it anymore to answer my own question. It is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: when using TouchableNativeFeedback, it has this square background (i dont mean ripple) How do we customize that (e.g. increase its size, make it round, or maybe remove it and just have ripple alone) ?

Answer (score 13):

Well, This is how I typically decide what to use:

- If I'm building for Android-only, and the component is large enough that the native feedback will be visibly different than using the others then I use `TouchableNativeFeedback`
- If I want to control the opacity on the component or I want the button to have color when touched, and I don't want to control the focused state of some element inside the Touchable, then I use `TouchableHighlight`. (`TouchableOpacity` has got some weird parts when you control opacity yourself).
- In all other cases, I use `TouchableOpacity` because it's more "bare" than `TouchableHighlight`

Comment: This answer is a helpful start… but I was hoping to find more solid technical and/or design related reasons for why to use one vs another.

Answer (score 4):

I think the main essential difference as stated in Docs:

`TouchableHighlight must have one child (not zero or more than one). If you wish to have several child components, wrap them in a View.`[link](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchablehighlight.html)

**TouchableHighlight**

> TouchableHighlight A wrapper for making views respond properly to
>   touches. On press down, the opacity of the wrapped view is decreased,
>   which allows the underlay color to show through, darkening or tinting
>   the view.
>
> The underlay comes from wrapping the child in a new View, which can
>   affect layout, and sometimes cause unwanted visual artifacts if not
>   used correctly, for example if the backgroundColor of the wrapped view
>   isn't explicitly set to an opaque color.

**TouchableOpacity**

> TouchableOpacity # A wrapper for making views respond properly to
>   touches. On press down, the opacity of the wrapped view is decreased,
>   dimming it.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to

- highlight button on press — use `TouchableHighlight`
- change button's opacity on press — use `TouchableOpacity`

Comment: I think the author is aware of this a is asking for some more complex answer.

Comment: Furthermore, you can even use `<TouchableHighlight underlayColor="transparent" />`... and Facebook mixes all of those in their F8 App https://github.com/fbsamples/f8app/blob/master/js/common/F8Touchable.js